# Integration problem: lrgexp

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

I want to calculate the following integration but it gives the error

> PolynomialGCD::lrgexp: Exponent is out of bounds for function PolynomialGCD.

The code is:

```
        Δ = 0.0001
        γ = 0.01
        ϵ = 10^10
        δ = 10^10
        ω = 10^10
        Λ = 10^12
        k = Sqrt[δ^2 + ω^2]

        Δ^2 γ^2 Integrate[
        E^(I (ϵ τ)/Λ) (((2 k Cos[k τ] + 
        I ω Sin[k τ]) (k^2 - δ^2 Sin[k τ]^2))/(
        k^2 (2 k Cos[k τ] - I ω Sin[k τ]))) (100/(
        1 + τ^2) + I ((2  τ)/(1 + τ^2)^2)), {τ, 
        0, ∞}]
```

I tried to solve with `NIntegrate`, but it gives

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections

How should I solve this integral?

Comment: Firstly, you should use NIntegrate with the method `Method -> {"DoubleExponentialOscillatory", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}` because your integral is highly oscillatory over 0 to infinity. Unfortunately it is far too oscillatory to converge within any reasonable error. What do you need this integral for?

Comment: Thanks. It is one of the coefficients of a differential equation describing the dynamics of a physical system. I think that since it contains a decreasing function it must converge somewhere.

Comment: All the Greek characters mean I cannot cut and paste this into Mathematica. At least not with a Ubuntu Linux clipboard.